# Select the first value and last value (chronologically) from a datastream in Xively

Tags: python, xively

How do you select the first value and last value (chronologically) from a datastream in Xively via Python?

I'm able to select a datapoint if I know its timestamp, `datastream.datapoints.get(at)`, but I would like to be able to select the first and last points without this prior knowledge.

EDIT: The below subquestion has been answered. Thank you @alkuzad and @cmd.
*For one approach, I tried to fetch and return a list of datapoints with `datastream.datapoints.history(start=start, end=end)`, but this returns `<generator object history at 0x107c37050>`, and I have no idea what to do with that. (I'm no expert in Python.)  Which leads to a subquestion: How do you access the generator object and print a list of datapoints?*

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: pass your generator to a list constructor to see something you are used to.  `list()`

Comment: I'm wondering this too. It's easy to get "current" values but not historical values or to scan through a series.

Answer (score 0):

Generator is object created with speed in mind. List items are generated at once, generator items are generated when needed. So you have to "ask" for each item separatelly.

`for datapoint in datastream.datapoints.history(start=start, end=end):
    print(datapoint) # Or whatever you have to do to print that`